# Magento 2 - Display out of stock product for only one category while hiding them in all other category

Tags: magento2, collection

How to display out of stock products only in one category with "Display Out Of Stock" option "No" in the admin?

Answer (score 0):

The out of stock filter is added to categories in a plugin method in `Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Plugin\Layer`.
If you want to hook into this logic you can create an around plugin method to the `beforePrepareProductCollection` method.
That can be done for example like this:

Add plugin definition in your di.xml:

```
<type name="Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Plugin\Layer">
    <plugin name="Yormodule_CatalogInventory_Layer" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\CatalogInventoryLayer" sortOrder="10" disabled="false"  />
</type>
```

Create a file in your module folder in Plugin/CatalogInventoryLayer.php with the following content

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

class CatalogInventoryLayer{

    protected $_logger;

    public function __construct( 
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
        ){
            $this->_logger = $logger;
    }

    public function aroundBeforePrepareProductCollection(
        \Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Plugin\Layer $subject,
        callable $proceed,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer $layer,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Collection\AbstractCollection $collection)
    {   
        //skip out of stock filter in Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Plugin::beforePrepareProductCollection 
        //for your category here - you may use some configuration for that
        $this->_logger->debug("my category id ... " . $layer->getCurrentCategory()->getId());
        if ($layer->getCurrentCategory()->getId() != [YOUR CATEGORY ID WITH OUT OF STOCK PRODUCTS]){
            return $proceed($layer,$collection);
        }

        return;
    }
}
```

Anyway it may be that there are some other calls affecting the building of the collection - in that case you should debug in `Magento\CatalogInventory\Helper\Stock::addIsInStockFilterToCollection` method

Comment: hi @HelgeB, its not working